# Is TFS services free forever?

Tags: azure-devops

I have seen at [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) free package for 5 users.

Is this free forever or for limited period of time? I mean is this for trial period?

Comment: probably not `forever`, they can change their free package at any moment, so I wouldn't count on it...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the [pricing information](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/tfs-information) on the site?  That's not a trial pricing model they're referring to. That's the arrangement that will be in place once they start charging.

I can't speak for what Microsoft will do with their pricing plans in the future but I'd be very surprised if they took away free features. If anything I'd expect it to move the other way based on competitive pressures.

Comment: link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 1):

The latest pricing structure has been posted since this service has been officially launched.  Check out their [Visual Studio Online pricing page](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs).

As Dave Chen said, Microsoft has made no promises as to what their pricing will be *forever*.  At this point in time, the Visual Studio Online Basic remains free for up to five users.  The tiers above Basic do not receive the free five user allotment.  Also, at this point in time, MSDN subscribers can join any Visual Studio Online project for free and do not count against the five free users.

All of this is subject to change.

Comment: Close, but not quite. VSO Basic is free for up to five users, not Basic and above. Your level of access depends on the level of your MSDN subscription. Here's a good rundown of the licenses: http://blog.nwcadence.com/visual-studio-online-explained/

Comment: @AndrewClear, thanks!  I've updated my answer to be more accurate based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have not announced the pricing model for Team Foundation Service yet.

Brian Harry's blog will probably see the announcment first.

[Here is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/26/a-few-more-visual-studio-2013-preview-features.aspx#10431095) his last comment on the matter.